# What winding pattern would be the most efficient for generating electricity?

Tags: diy, power-generation

I'm looking to build a hand crank or pedal powered generator for a personal project, almost completely from scratch. I'm making my own coils, and looking to see what pattern would be the best for it, three-phase, single-phase, DC with a commutator, or some other one I don't know yet. My own research was not doing well, I couldn't seem to find the right keywords to get results. If anyone has any tips it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you ignore friction and air resistance, any winding pattern you want will have about the same power efficiency.

Comment: A evil part of me wants to say *DC with a commutator*.  The easiest would be three-phase with three diodes to rectify into DC .  Which would be a BLDC generator.

Comment: three or more phases with a diode bridge will the be easiest. Your rotating magnetic field will lose power as eddy current in any iron core present, pretty much independent of the windings.